# Number that are not divisible

Tags: c++, algorithm

You will be given a positive integer N. Your task is to find the number of positive integers K ≤ N such that K is not divisible by any number among the set {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}.

I was thinking about all the prime numbers but it is not giving the correct answer.

Surprisingly,answer is very simple.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--) {
        long long n;
        cin>>n;
        long long ans = (n/2+n/3+n/5+n/7)-(n/6+n/10+n/14+n/15+n/21+n/35)+(n/30+n/42+n/70+n/105)-(n/210);
        cout<<n - ans<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But I did not understand this algo.Can anyone please explain me this algo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The primes in the set are 2, 3 ,5 and 7. Using these, we count:

```
how many numbers up to N are divisible by 2, 3, 5 and 7
```

but then we overcounted the numbers that are divisible by both:

```
2,3 = 6
2,5 = 10
2,7 = 14
etc.
```

but then we over-subtracted all the numbers divisible by all three of:

```
2,3,5 = 30
2,3,7 = 42
etc.
```

etc...

This combinatoric principle is called [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Whatever is left after this process was not divisible by those primes. (Note that if a number is not divisible by 2, it's not divisible by 4, 6, 8 and 10; same for 3 and 9.)

Answer (score 1):

First, count the numbers that aren't divisible by the prime numbers in the set.

- `n/2` of the numbers are not divisible by 2.
- `n/3` of the numbers are not divisible by 3.
- etc.

However, some numbers were counted twice. Numbers not divisible by 6 are neither divisible by 2 nor 3, so we subtract them from the total.

Numbers like 30 were counted *three* times in the first phase (as a multiple of 2, 3, and 5), but was accounted for *three* times in the second phase (as a multiple of 6, 10, and 15). So we have to add them in *again*, for a net contribution of 1.

So, each parenthesized expression in the final answer represents either counting the numbers not divisible by a number in the set, or compensating for a previous over- or undercount.

Answer (score 0):

There exists non-recursive solution.

```
int N = ....; 
int const primes[4] = {2,3,5,7};
int result = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)// 16 = 2^4
{ 
    int p = 1, s = 1; // s = (-1)^bits(i).
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        if ( ( i >> j ) & 1 ) 
            p *= primes[j], s *= -1;

    result += (N / p) * s; 
}
```